# Tee command in docker file

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

I am trying to install rethinkdb using below  dockerfile

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /etc/lsb-release" && echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" | tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list"
        RUN wget -qO- https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
        RUN sudo apt-get update
        RUN sudo apt-get install rethinkdb
```

Installation fails.Below is the output.

Output :

```
Step 22/23 : RUN sudo apt-get update
 ---> Running in 54d07239b6f3
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Seems like the sources list is not written correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your source command does not transfer the variables from /etc/lsb-release to the echo command. You need something like this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt $DISTRIB_CODENAME main"' | tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list"
```

Comment: Thanks,Works Perfectly.